# encountered this.state is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try running my code I get the `error this.setState is not a function` deos anyone know how I can correct this? Thanks!

```
spiele.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else     console.log(data)
        const ball = data;
        this.setState({
          ball
        }).bind(this)         
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `.bind` in the wrong place

```
spiele.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else     console.log(data)
        const ball = data;
        this.setState({
          ball
        }).bind(this)   // wrong      
      });
```

The `.bind` should be in `function(err, data)` not in `this.setState`

```
spiele.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else     console.log(data)
        const ball = data;
        this.setState({
          ball
        })       
      }.bind(this)); // correct
```